# Continuously monitor Systemd Journals

Tags: c, linux, logging, systemd, journal

I am working with systemd journals to create a custom log processing program. I am trying to work with sd_journal APIs but I have a couple of questions:

1. **Is it possible to listen the runtime journals** (SD_JOURNAL_RUNTIME_ONLY) without polling? SD_JOURNAL_FOREACH_DATA and sd_journal_get_data doesn't [say much](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=sd_journal_next&ampsect=3) about this.
2. In your opinion, **is this a good design**?
3. Is there a way to understand **where are the runtime logs getting forwarded**? I did "systemctl status systemd-journald.service" and the service status is running. However, when I am trying to read journals using sd_journal_open, it doesn't show any entry. I can see the entries through journalctl. I want to do this without reading journal files (by sniffing /run/log/journal which is a unix domain socket) to avoid disk io.

Here is the sample code I am using:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                         
#include <unistd.h>                                                                                        
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                        

#include <systemd/sd-journal.h>                                                                          
#include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>                                                                           

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {                                                                       

  int ret_val = 0;                                                                                       
  int count = 0;                                                                                         
  sd_journal *jd;                                                                                        

  sd_journal_print(LOG_INFO, "Hello World, this is PID %lu!", (unsigned long) getpid());                 

  do {                                                                                                   
    ret_val = sd_journal_open (&jd, SD_JOURNAL_SYSTEM | SD_JOURNAL_RUNTIME_ONLY | SD_JOURNAL_LOCAL_ONLY);
    if (ret_val != 0) {                                                                                  
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open journal: %s\n", strerror(-ret_val));                               
      break;                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                    

    printf ("Current Journal was loaded successfully!\n");                                               

    const void *d;                                                                                       
    size_t l;                                                                                            

    SD_JOURNAL_FOREACH_DATA (jd, d, l) {                                                                 
      printf("%.*s\n", (int)l, (const char*) d);                                                                                                                                                              
      count++;                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                    

    sd_journal_close(jd);                                                                                
    printf ("# of Journal entries read: %d\n", count);                                                          
  } while (0);                                                                                           
  return 0;                                                                                                  
}
```

Comment: ```journalctl -f``` doesn't do what you need? That's the entire system log streaming on stdout for you. If not, perhaps you could describe exactly what kind of information you need to extract from the log.

Comment: Journalctl does collect all the logs. In my case, certain privileged logs from journal needs to be processed further and massaged into for other subsystems. My requirement is

Comment: For a question this specific, consider asking through one of the systemd project communication channels directly.

Comment: @MarkStosberg I think this is a legitimate forum for such a question, but OP fails to describe what he's actually trying to do.

Comment: to read the in-memory recent journal entry and process them further.

Comment: @jforberg it's a legitimate forum, but I think he'll much much better luck getting answer directly from the that community given the detailed nature of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out but the problem was fairly simple. The problem was in the use of

```
SD_JOURNAL_RUNTIME_ONLY
```

while the `journald` **storage** was specified as **persistent**.

To me, it was non-intuitive that persistent journals doesn't go to runtime journal buffer. So the only way to simulate the functionality of `journalctl -f` was by opening the local journals and seek the tail.

Comment: Could you please help me. I am trying to reproduce the functionality of `journalctl --no-pager -u myservice` But your examples always prints "# of Journal entries read: 0".